# Should 10k tools look like that?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

No matter what I click I can't see the flagged post. But maybe I simply don't know something. Or maybe it's my browser, my firewall, my proxy etc. So what should I see?

[image]

Comment: Congrats on getting to 10k by the way :)

Comment: @Clive Thanks :) Dunno how it happened :P

Comment: Welcome to the 10k club.

Comment: @MPD Thank you :) So now only 15k, 20k and ♦ left to get. But I think it'll be a slow road that'll end at or before 20.

Comment: Now fixed - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212285/flagged-question-count-is-wrong/212286#212286

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, that's what the page looks like when there are no flags available to review.

It just so happens that the only flag currently in the review queue is one *you* flagged, so it doesn't make sense to show it to you again as you can't action it (excuse my publicly divulging that info, but I can't see it being a problem).

Why you see the `(1)` notification for flags, I'm not sure. I seem to remember the same thing happening for me before I got to 10k, and I'm sure I've seen questions about it on the main meta site before. But I can't find anything right now.

99 times out of 100 things like this can be blamed on cache.

Comment: OK, thanks. I just wanted to be sure it works, or to know I need to debug my settings if it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah I'd say that's working as expected - just a heads up though, we really don't get that many flags, so if you don't ever see anything on that page it might not indicate that there's a problem

Comment: Now I see notifications about 3 flags. And 4 on the right (3 types, one with 2x). And no questions in the area. Are all these flags mine? Should I file a bugreport on MSO? Sorry for bothering you here but I don't think it's worth separate question.

Comment: @Mołot As usual, it's caching that plays a role here. The number of flagged posts is cached for every user; talking in Drupalese, the cache is not [DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_USER](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/constant/DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_USER/7), and it shows you the same number everybody see. The only difference is between moderators and normal users.

Comment: @kiamlaluno thanks. I guess there wasn't much room for n00b questions about this particular tool ;)